# Why qmake-builded Qt Quick app uses threaded render loop, and same CMake-builded app uses basic render loop?

Tags: multithreading, qt, rendering, macos-catalina, scenegraph

Created two versions of empty Qt Quick Application.
First with qmake build system.
Second with CMake build system.

Added in each application following code for logging purposes:

```
#include <QLoggingCategory>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(R"(
qt.scenegraph.general=true
)");
```

First app (qmake-builded) output:

```
qt.scenegraph.general: threaded render loop
```

Second app (CMake-builded) output:

```
qt.scenegraph.general: QSG: basic render loop
```

Why qmake-builded app uses threaded render loop, and CMake-builded app uses basic render loop?
What make difference? Are there any options add by qmake or CMake?

System environment:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (19G2021)
- Qt 5.13.0
- Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)

Comment: Did you compare Makefiles generated by qmake and Cmake?